# Elements wider than window - CSS

Tags: html, css

When I check my website with Safari browser on smartphone (iPhone) or MacBook, then some elements of my website are wider than the browser window e.g. the `body`-tag. I have checked the website with dev-tool and it seems that it begins at a width of 600px and underneath. I dont see this problem in Chrome.

You can see a screenshot here and see that the window has a width of 375px but the `body`-tag is 439px wide.

[image: Screenshot]

I am applying this CSS-rules because I read this should solve the problem but it isn't for me, unfortunately.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is the website I am talking about: http://www.firma-info.no

I hope somebody has an advice for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use `display: flex` together with `flex-wrap` property: http://cssreference.io/property/flex-wrap/

Comment: You need to post a **minimal working example** to replicate the issue here in your question. Adding links to external sites is useless, since the question becomes ambiguous once the issue is solved. Please post your markup and CSS (the minimum amount required to replicate the behaviour) here.

Comment: @BenM I would like to add an example which shows the issue but if I add my markup in either jsfiddle or codepen the issue doesn't occur. But it is still there at my website. Do you have an advice on how I could replicate this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*I am testing on Firefox on Desktop in Responsive View*

But, I have found that the clouds in the background .`x1, .x2 etc.` are causing the window to be larger in width than expected.
This is the case when the clouds are towards the end of their animation.

A Simply `overflow: hidden;` to the `#page` does the job.

I don't know if this is causing your problem for sure but, it might help anyway.

---

*Also I'd recommend using transforms translate to move the clouds rather than margin inside your animation.*

Answer (score 2):

give a overflow-x: hidden on the body tag in css

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fix this by implementing bootstrap or setting the width to a percentage rather than a pixel size.

Bootstrap has special div classes for column size that adjusts with the screen size and is quite easy to implement

I.E.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12" align="center" id="content">
```

you need to implement this in the head tag of your document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This might fix the issue, but I don't believe that including 2 javascript files and a large framework + invalid html __align="center"__ is fitting for this problem.

Comment: sorry you can add 2 cols to the left and right when it is medium to center it when the page is large and just leave them blank as well.